# What is the difference between step into and step over when debugging?

Tags: ida, disassembly, debuggers, gdb, debugging

I am using EDB and stepping through the program but I do not even know what the difference in behavior is when doing this.  I feel like this is something I should know if I ever have hope of reverse engineering this program.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `gdb` terms (and commands) are `step` and `next` and the difference is that `step` continues to run until it changes line of source code, while `next` doesn't trace into a subroutine, but rather skips over it. The `stepi` and `nexti` commands are similar but operate at the machine instruction level rather than source code level. Read more in [The Fine Manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html#Continuing-and-Stepping).

Here's an example that may help clarify.  Let's say you have a simple project with three simple files:

### main.c

```
#include "squareit.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x = 5;
    printf("%d squared is %d\n", x, squareit(x));
}
```

### squareit.h

```
#ifndef SQUAREIT_H
#define SQUAREIT_H
// return the square of an integer
int squareit(int x);
#endif // SQUAREIT_H
```

### squareit.c

```
#include "squareit.h"

int squareit(int x) {
    return x*x;
}
```

We compile the program with debugging flags enabled (`gcc -g main.c squareit.c -o simple`) and then run `gdb simple`.  If we are sitting on the `printf` line and execute `step`, we will find ourselves in the `squareit()` function.  If instead at that same point we execute `next`, the `squareit()` function and the `printf()` functions will both execute and we will find ourselves on the last line of `main()`.

The session follows:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40113d: file ./main.c, line 5.
(gdb) run
Starting program: ./simple 

Breakpoint 1, main () at ./main.c:5
5       int x = 5;
(gdb) step
6       printf("%d squared is %d\n", x, squareit(x));
(gdb) s
squareit (x=5) at ./squareit.c:4
4       return x*x;
(gdb) s
5   }
(gdb) s
5 squared is 25
main () at ./main.c:7
7   }
(gdb) r
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: ./simple 

Breakpoint 1, main () at ./main.c:5
5       int x = 5;
(gdb) s
6       printf("%d squared is %d\n", x, squareit(x));
(gdb) next
5 squared is 25
7   }
```

The `gdb` commands used here are `b` to set a breakpoint, `s` which is an alias of `step`, `next` (has an alias of `n`) and `run` (has an alias of `r`).